# Using a Token to Pull Only the Year from a Date

Tags: civimail, civimember, tokens

I'm trying to set up membership renewal reminder letters, and instead of including the entire date that the member joined, we'd like it to just be the year. I have a token for "latestcurrentmembership.join_date" that adds that date as "January 1, 2022." Is there a way to have the token only add "2022" to the letter?

Answer (score 1):

I had been looking for something similar and wanted to follow up for anyone reading this post. (I would have left a comment on Demerit's answer but wanted to include a tad more info.)

I could not get the token modifiers listed to work in Civi 5.57.4 on Drupal 7, PHP 8.025 (even though it says they work in 5.43 and up, perhaps I have some customization causing a conflict).

I was able to get them to work on the Dmaster today though - it is running 5.61.alpha1 on Drupal 7 and PHP 7.4.33. I found that you can use those for core date but not custom date fields, here's a printout:

```
Date of birth  
{contact.birth_date} : December 1st, 1980
{contact.birth_date|crmDate:"Year"} : 1980

Custom Date token
{contact.custom_3} : 03/01/2023
{contact.custom_3|crmDate:"Year"} : 03/01/2023
```

I'm guessing that the fact that the custom date token formats differently out of the gate is part of the reason it doesn't work.

For fun, I also tried the smarty modifier |date_format:"%Y" but that produces an error: Invalid token filter: ["date_format","%Y"] so they've shored up that part of the code to help show errors.

---

Additional information based on Demerit's comments. While the crmDate token modifiers didn't work for a custom field Demerit was spot on.

> For the custom one, if you know the date format is always mm/dd/yyyy,
> you could do {capture
> assign=foo}{contact.custom_3}{/capture}{$foo|substring:6:4}, and
> actually I don't think you need the capture, just some quotes:
> {"{contact.custom_3}"|substring:6:4}

The capture method worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Just adding that even if date_format worked, it's deprecated since it uses strftime() which is deprecated in php.

Comment: For the custom one, if you know the date format is always mm/dd/yyyy, you could do `{capture assign=foo}{contact.custom_3}{/capture}{$foo|substring:6:4}`, and actually I don't think you need the capture, just some quotes: `{"{contact.custom_3}"|substring:6:4}`

Comment: Demerit, as always, you're a magician. I got the capture version to work!!! SUPER helpful! I will edit my answer to reflect your additions.

Answer (score 0):

It *might* work to use crmDate as described at https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/common-workflows/tokens-and-mail-merge/#date, i.e.

`{latestcurrentmembership.join_date|crmDate:"Year"}`

However not everything listed there works everywhere in all versions so I don't know offhand if that works in your version of civi in scheduled reminders. Only one way to find out!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but no luck when I tried it. I'll keep at!

Comment: Maybe {$latestcurrentmembership.join_date|date_format:"%Y"} ? That would however be using smarty - not sure if that works in scheduled reminders...